# Using Google Places searchBox to retrieve only address results

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am working on a map search using autocomplete where once a new address is selected, the current marker gets removed and replaced by the one the user searched for. To do this I am using the searchBox, however some results are being shown on the autocomplete that would not work, like "shopping" or "audi" which would add a marker for each place result all across the map. I am trying to make these results filter to addresses only but can't seem to make it work. I keep seeing the types: address attribute on the documentation but can't seem to figure out where this would go in this scenario. Any help is truly appreciated!! Here's my code:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.711383, -105.018230),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoomControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false
        });

        var myLatLng = {lat: 39.711383, lng: -105.018230};

        var icon = {
          url: "../../../images/gold-delivery-128.png",
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 64)
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: icon
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          marker.setVisible(false);

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: "../../../images/gold-delivery-128.png",
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 64)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);

        });
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SearchBox doesn't allow any filtering (its only option is a `google.maps.LatLngBounds`)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBoxOptions).  Another option would be [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions), which accepts a [`type` option](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3).  You can see if one of those supports your use case (perhaps `geocode` or `establishment` would work).

Comment: Thank you!! Using autocomplete instead of searchbox did the trick and allowed me to filter the results using geocode.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is the filtering of the results, like this:

```
 // Clear out the old markers.
 markers.forEach(function(marker) {
   marker.setMap(null);
 });
 markers = [];

 marker.setVisible(false);

 <!---- Filtering the results : start ------>
 places = places.filter(function(place) {
   return place.types.indexOf('locality') > -1 ||
          place.types.indexOf('political') > -1;
 });
 <!---- Filtering the results : end ------>

 // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 places.forEach(function(place) {
   ...
```

Supported types are here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types